# Can I install ubuntu phone on samsung galaxy light using a Windows PC?

Tags: ubuntu-touch

I have read through the install information on the ubuntu wiki and am left wondering if I can use a Windows computer instead of an ubuntu computer in those steps using a different package, or if there are other sets of steps which will allow me to use such a computer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the list at [this page](http://developer.ubuntu.com/en/start/ubuntu-for-devices/devices/) your device is not supported.
Moreover, Ubuntu is necessary to make all the scripts and binaries working during the flashing procedures. 
I guess it might be possible to disassemble al this stuff and make it working on windows, but it would require an enormous effort which is not necessary, just try with a virtual installation (look for virtualbox) or with Wubi